Imposing optimization constraints on linked variables
Say I have a discrete non-linear programming problem,
$$ \min_\textbf{x} \quad \Sigma^N_{n=0} J(\textbf{x}_n)$$
with $\textbf{x}_n = [x_1, x_2]_n$, and some non-linear constraints on $x_1$ and $x_2$. Suppose the constraints are that $x_2$ must always be some $f(x_1)$, and that $x_2[N] > 0$ (indexing denoted by $[\cdot]$ here).
It is possible to compose this problem in two ways:
(1) Optimization with two variables and explicit constraints:
\begin{align}
\min_\textbf{x} \quad \Sigma^N_{n=0} & J(\textbf{x}_n)\\\\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad
 x_2 &= f(x_1) \\\\
 x_2[N] &> 0.
\end{align}
(2) Optimization with one variable and 'implicit' constraint:
\begin{align}
\min_{x_1} \quad \Sigma^N_{n=0} & J([x_1, f(x_1)]_n) \\\\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad
& f(x_1)[N] > 0.
\end{align}
In (1), a solver has to work with two 'free' variables that are linked by $f$ (non-linear), with one of them carrying an additional constraint. In (2), the solver has only one variable, the second variable is 'constructed' from it to compute cost and constraints. In a general non-linear solver (like Matlab's fmincon), the cost and constraint operations are simple function calls that allow the user to hide these operations, so (2) uses a more 'complicated' constraint.
I think the two forms are mathematically equivalent (please correct me if I'm wrong).
My question is whether one form is better suited for numerical optimization routines than the other? For larger problems with many variables, is it better to use/expose all variables as optimization variables and then add constraints linking them, or use only the 'true' independent variables while hiding the dependent ones to enforce constraints?

I would say they are theoretically equivalent, but may have differences in practice. A balance is to be found, most likely empirically, between the difficulty of optimizing one of these problems with its constraints, and its cost (form (1) has more variables).
Also, the form (1) may lead to some iterates being unfeasible with respect to the first constraint, i.e. $x_2 \neq f(x_1)$. On the opposite, form (2) always ensures that this is satisfied.
Similarly, form (1) has a linear constraint on $x_2$, which can be ensured to be satisfied at all iterates (maybe dependent on the solver choice), whereas form (2) may lead to initial iterates which have $x_2<0$. Maybe these temporary infeasibilities could cause issues in some models that you use under the hood (e.g. non-negativity requirement) ?
